# tree command shown Chinese character as unicode

Tags: macos, terminal, internationalization

`(env) ➜  zhuaxia git:(master) ✗ tree /tmp/test`
/tmp/test
└── 谢211220_3_8
    ├── album_description.txt
    ├── cover.jpg
    ├── 谢211220;210\230浩231_3_8.mp3
    └── 谢211220_3_8.mp3

`(env) ➜  zhuaxia git:(master) ✗ ls /tmp/test`
谢安琪_3_8

Using `tree` command, some Chinese character is displayed as Unicode, but `ls` is OK.

Comment: I did not found the solution, but I found the error happens only when I sshed to Ubuntu from Mac OS X.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have problems same as you, but I did Google and found the answer! Just add the option

```
tree -N /name_of_directory
```

`man tree` reads:

```
-N     Print non-printable characters as is instead of as escaped octal numbers.
```

Tell me if this still does not work!

Also, you seem to use `zsh`?? I am not familiar with that. I use `bash`, though.

Comment: Worked perfectly with homebrew installed tree (on MacOS X). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the dashes that results in indentation in tree rendering was replaced with some strange character 'a' with a hat. Either `tree -A` or `LC_ALL= C tree` would resolve the issue then.